# How to average two heat maps of kernel density estimates in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, kernel-density

I am trying to average multiple heat maps of kernel density estimates to create a single heat map. The goal is to take locations of animals encountered on a survey and create a heat map using kernel density estimates.

This is simple to do in program R using the `stat_density2d` function in ***ggplot2*** with a base map. However, on some occasions there were replicate surveys (the same area was surveyed twice or three times).

In this case, I would like to create a heat map for each replicate survey and then average the two (or three) heat maps to create a mean density map.

Is there a way to average two heat maps, as opposed to averaging the points from two data sets then creating a heat map from the average points?

Here is some example code that represents the data I am working with. There are locations from two replicate surveys, and a heat map of both replicates. I would like to average these two heat maps to create one heat maps. Rather than averaging the points I'd like to average the heat maps themselves.

```
#Replicate 1
x1 <- runif(50, min=1, max=4)
y1 <- runif(50, min=7, max=9)

#Replicate 2
x2 <- runif(40, min=4, max=7)
y2 <- runif(40, min=2, max=5)

#Plot heat map of both replicates
 ggplot() +
   xlim(0, 10) +
   ylim(0, 10) + 
   stat_density2d(aes(x = x1, y = y1, 
                      fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), 
                  bins = 7, geom = "polygon") + 
   scale_alpha(guide = FALSE) +
   stat_density2d(aes(x = x2, y = y2,
                      fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                  bins = 7, geom = "polygon")
```

[Figure with two heat map clusters from two replicate surveys, generated from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXeo.png)

[I would like to generate something like this by averaging the two heat map clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Andqy.png)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just combine the data into one dataset? I guess how you "should" combine them is really more of a statistics question that's probably better for [stats.se]. I'm not sure how you'd define taking the average of two heat maps. What kind of interpretation do you want the resulting plot to have? There's not really a specific programming question here that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I agree that this is probably more of a statistics questions than a simple programming question. I know that in ArcGIS, once a rasterized kernel density estimate surface (aka heat map) has been created for each replicate, you can average each together using the Map Algebra Tool to create a mean heat map.  I was hoping that someone would know the programming necessary to do a similar approach in program R.